# No se pudo realizar una llamada a SSPI; consulte la excepción interna C# TLS

Tags: c#, ssl, tls

Estoy tratando de conectarme a un dispositivo intellinac de verifone, a través de SSL/TLS,
sin embargo recibo ese mensaje "No se pudo realizar una llamada a SSPI; consulte la excepción interna " la excepción interna dice "InnerException = {"Por lo menos uno de los parámetros transmitidos a la función no es válido"}", le he cambiado los valores a los parámetros pero no identifico que puede ser.

La excepcion la recibo en este llamado:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(IssuerServer, xc, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
```

En el intellinac  no se esta usando la autenticación de cliente, y tiene habilitado TLS 1.1 , 1.2 y SSLv3

El codigo demo es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SSL
{

   class Program
  {
    static string IssuerServer;
    static int IssuerPort;
    static bool IssuerSSL;
    private static char[] hexDigits = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
    private static IDictionary<char, int> hexDigitsToInt = new Dictionary<char, int>() {
            {'0', 0}, {'1', 1}, {'2', 2}, {'3', 3}, {'4', 4}, {'5', 5}, {'6', 6}, {'7', 7}, {'8', 8}, {'9', 9},
            {'A', 10}, {'B', 11}, {'C', 12}, {'D', 13}, {'E', 14}, {'F', 15},
            {'a', 10}, {'b', 11}, {'c', 12}, {'d', 13}, {'e', 14}, {'f', 15}
        };

    public static byte[] StringToHex(String val, bool isLeftAligned)
    {
      if (val == null) return null;
      int length = val.Length;
      if (length % 2 == 1)
      {
        val = isLeftAligned ? val + "0" : "0" + val;
        length++;
      }
      length = length / 2;
      byte[] retVal = new byte[length];
      char[] chars = val.ToUpper().ToCharArray();
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
        char ch = chars[2 * i];
        if (!hexDigitsToInt.ContainsKey(ch)) return null;
        int upper = hexDigitsToInt[ch];
        ch = chars[2 * i + 1];
        if (!hexDigitsToInt.ContainsKey(ch)) return null;
        int lower = hexDigitsToInt[ch];
        retVal[i] = (byte)((upper << 4) | lower);
      }
      return retVal;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="val"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] StringToHex(String val)
    {
      return StringToHex(val, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="val"></param>
    /// <param name="length"></param>
    /// <param name="isLeftAligned"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] StringToHex(String val, int length, bool isLeftAligned)
    {
      if (val != null)
      {
        if (val.Length < length)
        {
          val = val.PadLeft(length, '0');
        }
        else if (val.Length > length)
        {
          val = val.Substring(val.Length - length, length);
        }
      }
      return StringToHex(val, isLeftAligned);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="val"></param>
    /// <param name="length"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] StringToHex(String val, int length)
    {
      return StringToHex(val, length, false);
    }

    static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
            object sender,
            X509Certificate certificate,
            X509Chain chain,
            SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("certificate.Subject [{0}]", certificate.Subject);
      if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
      {

        return true;

      }

       Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

      // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
      return false;
    }

    static void Tx()
    {
      TcpClient client = null;
      NetworkStream netStream = null;
      SslStream sslStream = null;
      try
      {


        IssuerSSL = true;
        IssuerServer = "someip";
        IssuerPort = 9999;
   

        byte[] byBufferOut = StringToHex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
        
        int totalBytesRcvd = 0;

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        client = new TcpClient(IssuerServer, IssuerPort);

        netStream = client.GetStream();

        sslStream = new SslStream(
                 client.GetStream(),
                 false,
                 new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                 null
                 );

        X509Certificate2Collection xc = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(IssuerServer, xc, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);

        sslStream.Write(byBufferOut, 0, byBufferOut.Length);
        sslStream.Flush();
        sslStream.ReadTimeout = 120000;

        client.ReceiveBufferSize = 4000;

        if (netStream.CanRead)
        {
          byte[] readBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

          using (var writer = new MemoryStream())
          {
            do
            {
              int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

               numberOfBytesRead = sslStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);

              if (numberOfBytesRead <= 0)
              {
                throw new Exception("Connection closed prematurely.");
              }
              writer.Write(readBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
              totalBytesRcvd += numberOfBytesRead;
            } while (netStream.DataAvailable);


          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " || " + ex.InnerException.Message );
      }
      finally
      {
        if (sslStream != null)
        {
          sslStream.Flush();
          sslStream.Close();
        }
        if (netStream != null)
        {
          netStream.Flush();
          netStream.Close();
        }
        if (client != null)
        {
          client.Close();
        }
      }

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Tx();
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné agregando en el conectionstring la siguiente instrucción:

**SslMode = 0**;

ó

**SslMode = "Ninguno"**;

En el caso particular para Mysql podría ser de esta forma:

```
conn_string.Server = "192.168.XX.XXX";
conn_string.UserID = "XXX";
conn_string.Password = "XXX";
conn_string.Database = "XXX";
conn_string.SslMode = 0;

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader consultar;
            using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString()))
            using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
```

Comment: Excelente solución. lo aplique en app.config y funciono!
Gracias.